# How will partitioning affect my current queries in MySQL? When is it time to partition my tables?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that contains 1.5 million rows, has 39 columns, contains sales data of around 2 years, and grows every day.
I had no problems with it until we moved it to a new server, we probably have less memory now.

Queries are currently taking a very long time. Someone suggested partitioning the large table that is causing most of the performance issues but I have a few questions.

1. Is it wise to partition the table I described and is it
   likely to improve its performance?
2. If I do partition it, will
   I have to make changes to my current INSERT or SELECT statements or
   will they continue working the same way?
3. Does the partition
   take a long time to perform? I worry that with the slow performance,
   something would happen midway through and I would lose the data.
4. Should I be partioning it to years or months? (we usually
   look at the numbers within the month, but sometimes we take weeks or
   years). And should I also partition the columns? (We have some
   columns that we rarely or never use, but we might want to use them
   later)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I agree with Bill's answer; I will approach the Question in a different way.)

> When is it time to partion my tables?

Probably never.

> is it likely to improve its performance?

It is more likely to decrease performance a little.

> I have a table that contains 1.5 million rows

Not big enough to bother with partitioning.

> Queries are currently taking a very long time

*Usually* that is due to the lack of a good index, probably a 'composite' one.  *Secondly* is the formulation of the query.  Please show us a slow query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

> data of around 2 years, and grows every day

Will you eventually purge "old" data?  If so, the `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` is an excellent idea.  However, it only helps during the purge.  This is because `DROP PARTITION` is a *lot* faster than `DELETE...`.

> we probably have less memory now.

If you are mostly looking at "recent" data, then the size of memory (cf `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) *may* not matter.  This is due to caching.  However, it sounds like you are doing table scans, perhaps unnecessarily.

> will I have to make changes to my current INSERT or SELECT

No.  But you *probably* need to change what column(s) are in the `PRIMARY KEY` and secondary key(s).

> Does the partition take a long time to perform?

Slow - yes, because it will copy the entire table over.  Note: that means extra disk space, and the partitioned table will take more disk.

> something would happen midway through and I would lose the data.

Do not worry.  The new table is created, then a very quick `RENAME TABLE` swaps it into place.

> Should I be partioning it to years or months?

Rule of thumb:  aim for about 50 partitions.  With "2 years and growing", a likely choice is "monthly".

> we usually look at the numbers within the month, but sometimes we take weeks or years

Smells like a typical "Data Warehouse" dataset?  Build and incrementally augment a "Summary table" with daily stats.  With that table, you can quickly get weekly/monthly/yearly stats -- possibly 10 times as fast.  Ditto for any date range.  This also significantly helps with "low memory".

> And should I also partition the columns? (We have some columns that we rarely or never use, but we might want to use them later)

You should 'never' use `SELECT *`; instead, specify the columns you actually need.  "Vertical partitioning" is the term for your suggestion.  It is *sometimes* practical.  But we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` *with realistic column names* to discuss further.

More on partitioning: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
More on Summary tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Answer (score 6):

In most circumstances, you're better off using **indexes** instead of partitioning as your main method of query optimization.

The first thing you should learn about partitioning in MySQL is this rule:

> *All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have.*

Read more about this rule here: [Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html).

This rule makes many tables ineligible for partitioning, because you might want to partition by a column that is not part of the primary or unique key in that table.

The second thing to know is that partitioning only helps queries using conditions that unambiguously let the optimizer infer which partitions hold the data you're interested in. This is called Partition Pruning. If you run a query that could find data in any or all partitions, MySQL must search all the partitions, and you gain no performance benefit compared to have a regular non-partitioned table.

For example, if you partition by date, but then you run a query for data related to a specific user account, it would have to search all your partitions.

In fact, it might even be a little bit *slower* to use partitioned tables in such a query, because MySQL has to search each partition serially.

You asked how long it would take to partition the table. Converting to a partitioned table requires an `ALTER TABLE` to restructure the data, so it takes about the same time as any other alteration that copies the data to a new tablespace. This is proportional to the size of the table, but varies a lot depending on your server's performance. You'll just have to test it out, there's no way we can estimate how long it will take on your server.